# How can I define a recursive function type in scala?

Tags: scala, function, recursion, types

I would like, in scala, to define a function type something like:

```
type RFcn: () => RFcn
```

but I can't figure out a syntax to get it to work.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sarvesh's answer triggered something in my mind that gave me what I wanted.  It's pretty simple:

```
abstract class RFcn extends Function0[RFcn]
```

That does what I was trying to express.

Answer (score 0):

Well... the thing is that a `recursive function` is not supposed to return a `function`. And this `type RFcn = () => RFcn` does not look like a recursive function. So your question seems inspired from a bit of mis-understanding about recursive functions and is kind of invalid.

This `type RFcn = () => RFcn` looks more like a naive attempt towards implementing a state representing some step in a `potential Bottom` (read as potentially infinite computation). And if that is what you are after then you can change your question accordingly and may be something like a `State monad` can be useful to you.

Not lets come to part that can be answered. In Scala, funtions are acutally instances of `Function1`, `Function2`... etc. So if you want to have a type that represents a function from unit to function you can write as follows,

```
type UnitToFunc1[P1, R] = () => Function1[P1, R]

type UnitToFunc2[P1, P2, R] = () => Function2[P1, P2, R]
```

Comment: It's the type that I want to be recursive, not the function.  Read the title as "Recursive (function type)", not, "(Recursive function) type".  It's not that I need it to return a function, it's that I want it to return a function that returns a function that returns a function....

Comment: And that is exactly what I am trying to tell you... I think you want to implement a potential bottom. You can not directly represent a bottom in any turing complete language (and Scala is one of them) and thus people approximate them with potential bottoms. And State monad can be used to implement a potential bottom.

Comment: Now you may ask what do I mean by a potential bottom - A potential bottom or potential infinite computation is the state of that infinite computation at any given time. The important thing to note here is that although the final result of an infinite computation can not be represented, you can represent its intermediate state at any given time. And then just use that as a lazy generator for ongoing states.

Comment: There is no danger of infinite recursion - it's not executing the return value, it's just returning it.

Comment: Well... When you said that `I want it to return a function that returns a function that returns a function....`, I don't see how is this any different from an infinite evaluation. I have provided you with all that I think you needed to know... whether you try to understand it or not is up to you.

Comment: And if you think that something like a State monad is too complicated, you can find a simpler solution if you think about any `Tree` implementation in Scala. You should be able to observe the similarity here in the fact that every tree can have a child tree which can have a child tree which can have a child tree....

Comment: It doesn't evaluate the function, it just returns it.... see the answer I provided (your mention of the Function1 class clued me in to it)